# How do I debug a Xamarin AIDL Bound Service with Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a solution in Visual Studio with a Xamarin project that depends on another xamarin project inside the solution, and the comunication is made via AIDL.

If I deploy both projects separately to the Android emulator, It works flawlessly. The form is able to call the bound service. If otherwise I try to hit the "play" button to debug the application, it is not able to bind to the service via AIDL and I don't know why.

If I try to hit play having the service as startup project, it just deploys it and do nothing else.

I am not able to set breakpoints in the bound service and hit them.

I also tried to attach the debugger to the running process. But Visual Studio does not show me an option to do that with an Android application. =/

What is the best way to debug a xamarin project which depends on a bounded service (AIDL)?

Is there a better approach to expose a service to another Android application in such a way that I am able to reuse .net code and debug things naturaly?

Comment: do you mean debug the binding library?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT yes the binding library. Something like this for example:

internal class ApplierServiceBinder : IApplierServiceStub, Com.Boticario.Mobile.Motordepromocoes.IApplierService

Comment: you can try to test it with the offiical sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/bound-services  if it doesn't work, you can post a feedback on vs to see how it goes.